# Can I handle back button within methods in vuejs 2?

Tags: vuejs2

I need some help in vuejs 2. I want to detect back button pressed event. I did some research and found this,

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallBackFunction, false");
```

I think it is global event. I need something local, within a method. where i can use some logic.

```
methods: {
    backButtonPressed() {
    }
}
```

Or can i bind the global one to local function? Can anyone help me with that? TIA

Comment: backbutton event is used in [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html), are you building your app for smartphones?

Comment: if you are using vue-router and if you need to (validate some data or display some alert) before navigating away from a route then you can try using beforeLeave guard .

Comment: @choasia yes i'm building app for smartphones. and i already tried backbutton event. But i have to handle it globally. Is there any way i can handle it within methods: {} ?

Comment: @divine thanks for your reply. But i don't thing vue-route will solve my problem. I am trying to build a mobile app where i need to listen when user click mobile back button.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add the event on your `mounted` method on your root Vue component (the one the Vue instance is tied to.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  methods: {
    yourCallBackFunction () {
      // Your logic
    }
  }
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.yourCallBackFunction, false);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    document.removeEventListener("backbutton", this.yourCallBackFunction);
  }
})
```

We also remove it on `beforeDestroy` to keep things tidy.

Note: I've not personally used the back button event so have added it to this example only because you say it's working but need a way to globally handle it. This code will do just that.

Note: As per @Luke's comment - we add the listener in the mounted event so it doesn't execute for in the SSR context. If SSR isn't a factor / consideration then we can use the `created` lifecycle hook.

Comment: bro.. thanks for your reply.. and yes its works. But there is a little bit correction in your code.

document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.backbuttonpressed, false);

you should edit this , then i will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Use `mounted` instead of `created` to make it work in CSR only. This code should not be executed in SSR.

Comment: Tried this solution both in Chrome Android and Desktop - both are not working

Comment: Did not worki for me. Tested on Chrome and Safari desktop.

Comment: @AndrewBogdanov and Derzu I asked this question for my android app. It is not intended for any browser back button detection.

Answer (score 11):

If still someone come across this issue.
A solution for an event listener for browser-back is https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

```js
window.onpopstate = function() {
  alert('browser-back');
};
```

Comment: I got a weird behaviour where onpopstate is being fired when I change routes with vue, not only when I click on the browser's back button.

Comment: how can I use one of my vue methods in place of alert('browser-back')?  let say I want to close a popup on backbutton and I have a method hide() but when I tried this.hide() inside it error is "this.hide is not a function"..

Comment: @HassanSaqib you should use an arrow function to have "this":
window.onpopstate = () => {
  alert('browser-back');
};

Comment: Carl's problems are because the popstate event fires AFTER vue router does its checks...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vue-router(no idea if you don't, why...) a good solution is to use in your component:

```
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
 if (from.name === 'nameOfFromRoute' && to.name === 'nameOfToRoute' ) {
   next(false);
 } else {
   next();
 }
 console.log({ to, from });
```

},

Answer (score 3):

Is easy, if you need to catch that behavior only your component, you can use `beforeRouteLeave` function in the root of your component.

Example:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
 const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave?')
   if (answer) {
      next()
   } else {
      next(false)
   }
 }
```

But if you need to add this behavior globally, you need catch with `beforeEnter` in the routes.

Comment: It doesn't work when clicking on the browser's back button

Comment: What's the code of your button?

Answer (score 2):

This was one variation I found to work as well, a little less verbose and uses `router.push` in the beforeDestroy lifecycle method

- Listen for popstate
- Push the desired name/path to redirect

The code below would be a better understanding.

```
beforeDestroy() {
  window.addEventListener("popstate", (event) => {
    this.$router.push({ path: <your path> });
  });
},
```

This implementation was on *Nuxt 2.14.6* and works just as well with all versions of Vue.

Answer (score -3):

I have a similar problem and solved using **@click="backFunction"**
and created the function on methods like this:

```
methods: {
backFunction(){
//yourlogic
},
```

Comment: This won't detect when the back button(of the phone! not one in your page) gets triggered. Will only work for the button you created on your page.